# JSON onResponse - List will not populate with data

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am getting a working app (kinda). It is meant to populate the screen from a request for JSON data. I thought what I have so far would work but I guess not.
`onResponse` does not seem to ever be called so the data is never assigned to a variable to be processed and I don't know how to fix this. Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Below is my relevant  code:

My JSON data is:

```
{
   "popular":[
      {
         "name":"Pizza",
         "imageURL":"https://static4.depositphotos.com/1016418/315/i/600/depositphotos_3158962-stock-photo-pepperoni-pizza-isolated.jpg",
         "rating":"4.8",
         "deliveryTime":"45 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"Free Delivery",
         "price":"15",
         "note":"Delicious"
      },
      {
         "name":"Chick-Fil-A",
         "imageURL":"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/chicken-bacon-club-sandwich-picture-id585602032?k=6&m=585602032&s=612x612&w=0&h=DzlMVMOaqC25Zf78NPGzr9nLOf7wANEgv9u_vScu4d8=",
         "rating":"5.0",
         "deliveryTime":"15 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"3",
         "price":"7",
         "note":"Classic"
      },
      {
         "name":"Mac & Cheese",
         "imageURL":"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/homemade-baked-creamy-macaroni-and-cheese-picture-id483485720?k=6&m=483485720&s=612x612&w=0&h=u2Wb4hR0cIqNAm8q_4j-oFPrtC4hT_YXaq2srA2zmqI=",
         "rating":"4.7",
         "deliveryTime":"20 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"1",
         "price":"4",
         "note":"Homestyle"
      }
   ],
   "recommended":[
      {
         "name":"Chicken Tikka Masala",
         "imageURL":"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/chicken-tikka-masala-curry-with-rice-and-naan-bread-picture-id1143530019?k=6&m=1143530019&s=612x612&w=0&h=aOCxTVcwi88NHCX9-xgNu7cmPX9rq5AGtEVYblNTnGc=",
         "rating":"4.8",
         "deliveryTime":"25 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"2",
         "price":"14",
         "note":"Fan Favorite"
      },
      {
         "name":"Strawberry Milkshake",
         "imageURL":"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/strawberry-milkshake-covered-whipped-cream-plastic-glass-isolated-white-background-44432579.jpg",
         "rating":"4.5",
         "deliveryTime":"10 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"0",
         "price":"4",
         "note":"Chilly"
      },
      {
         "name":"3 Tacos",
         "imageURL":"https://previews.123rf.com/images/gdolgikh/gdolgikh1703/gdolgikh170300221/74432760-mexican-tacos-with-beef.jpg",
         "rating":"4.6",
         "deliveryTime":"17 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"1",
         "price":"12",
         "note":"Hard or Soft Shell"
      }
   ],
   "allmenu":[
      {
         "name":"Pizza",
         "imageURL":"https://static4.depositphotos.com/1016418/315/i/600/depositphotos_3158962-stock-photo-pepperoni-pizza-isolated.jpg",
         "rating":"4.8",
         "deliveryTime":"45 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"Free Delivery",
         "price":"15",
         "note":"Delicious"
      },
      {
         "name":"Chick-Fil-A",
         "imageURL":"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/chicken-bacon-club-sandwich-picture-id585602032?k=6&m=585602032&s=612x612&w=0&h=DzlMVMOaqC25Zf78NPGzr9nLOf7wANEgv9u_vScu4d8=",
         "rating":"5.0",
         "deliveryTime":"15 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"3",
         "price":"7",
         "note":"Classic"
      },
      {
         "name":"Mac & Cheese",
         "imageURL":"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/homemade-baked-creamy-macaroni-and-cheese-picture-id483485720?k=6&m=483485720&s=612x612&w=0&h=u2Wb4hR0cIqNAm8q_4j-oFPrtC4hT_YXaq2srA2zmqI=",
         "rating":"4.7",
         "deliveryTime":"20 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"1",
         "price":"4",
         "note":"Homestyle"
      },
      {
         "name":"Chicken Tikka Masala",
         "imageURL":"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/chicken-tikka-masala-curry-with-rice-and-naan-bread-picture-id1143530019?k=6&m=1143530019&s=612x612&w=0&h=aOCxTVcwi88NHCX9-xgNu7cmPX9rq5AGtEVYblNTnGc=",
         "rating":"4.8",
         "deliveryTime":"25 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"2",
         "price":"14",
         "note":"Fan Favorite"
      },
      {
         "name":"Strawberry Milkshake",
         "imageURL":"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/strawberry-milkshake-covered-whipped-cream-plastic-glass-isolated-white-background-44432579.jpg",
         "rating":"4.5",
         "deliveryTime":"10 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"0",
         "price":"4",
         "note":"Chilly"
      },
      {
         "name":"3 Tacos",
         "imageURL":"https://previews.123rf.com/images/gdolgikh/gdolgikh1703/gdolgikh170300221/74432760-mexican-tacos-with-beef.jpg",
         "rating":"4.6",
         "deliveryTime":"17 min",
         "deliveryCharges":"1",
         "price":"12",
         "note":"Hard or Soft Shell"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have models for `Allmenu`, `FoodData`, `Popular`, and `Recommended`.

AllMenu:

```
package com.example.bearcateats.model;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Allmenu {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("imageURL")
    @Expose
    private String imageURL;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private String rating;
    @SerializedName("deliveryTime")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryTime;
    @SerializedName("deliveryCharges")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryCharges;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("note")
    @Expose
    private String note;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getDeliveryTime() {
        return deliveryTime;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTime(String deliveryTime) {
        this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
    }

    public String getDeliveryCharges() {
        return deliveryCharges;
    }

    public void setDeliveryCharges(String deliveryCharges) {
        this.deliveryCharges = deliveryCharges;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

FoodData:

```
package com.example.bearcateats.model;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class FoodData {

    @SerializedName("popular")
    @Expose
    private List<Popular> popular = null;
    @SerializedName("recommended")
    @Expose
    private List<Recommended> recommended = null;
    @SerializedName("allmenu")
    @Expose
    private List<Allmenu> allmenu = null;

    public List<Popular> getPopular() {
        return popular;
    }

    public void setPopular(List<Popular> popular) {
        this.popular = popular;
    }

    public List<Recommended> getRecommended() {
        return recommended;
    }

    public void setRecommended(List<Recommended> recommended) {
        this.recommended = recommended;
    }

    public List<Allmenu> getAllmenu() {
        return allmenu;
    }

    public void setAllmenu(List<Allmenu> allmenu) {
        this.allmenu = allmenu;
    }

}
```

Popular:

```
package com.example.bearcateats.model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Popular {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("imageURL")
    @Expose
    private String imageURL;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private String rating;
    @SerializedName("deliveryTime")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryTime;
    @SerializedName("deliveryCharges")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryCharges;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("note")
    @Expose
    private String note;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getDeliveryTime() {
        return deliveryTime;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTime(String deliveryTime) {
        this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
    }

    public String getDeliveryCharges() {
        return deliveryCharges;
    }

    public void setDeliveryCharges(String deliveryCharges) {
        this.deliveryCharges = deliveryCharges;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

Recommended:

```
package com.example.bearcateats.model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Recommended {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("imageURL")
    @Expose
    private String imageURL;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private String rating;
    @SerializedName("deliveryTime")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryTime;
    @SerializedName("deliveryCharges")
    @Expose
    private String deliveryCharges;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("note")
    @Expose
    private String note;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getDeliveryTime() {
        return deliveryTime;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTime(String deliveryTime) {
        this.deliveryTime = deliveryTime;
    }

    public String getDeliveryCharges() {
        return deliveryCharges;
    }

    public void setDeliveryCharges(String deliveryCharges) {
        this.deliveryCharges = deliveryCharges;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

Main:

```
package com.example.bearcateats;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.bearcateats.adapters.PopularAdapter;
import com.example.bearcateats.adapters.RecommendedAdapter;
import com.example.bearcateats.model.Allmenu;
import com.example.bearcateats.model.FoodData;
import com.example.bearcateats.model.Popular;
import com.example.bearcateats.model.Recommended;
import com.example.bearcateats.retrofit.ApiInterface;
import com.example.bearcateats.retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.bearcateats.adapters.AllMenuAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ApiInterface apiInterface;

    RecyclerView popularRecyclerView, recommendedRecyclerView, allMenuRecyclerView;

    PopularAdapter popularAdapter;
    RecommendedAdapter recommendedAdapter;
    AllMenuAdapter allMenuAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<FoodData>> call = apiInterface.getAllData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<FoodData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Response<List<FoodData>> response) {
                System.out.println("TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                List<FoodData> MenuList;
                MenuList = response.body();
                if(MenuList == null) {
                    System.out.println("MenuList!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                }

                List <FoodData> test1 = (List<FoodData>) MenuList.get(0);

                List<Popular> popular = ((FoodData) test1).getPopular();

                getPopularData(popular);
                System.out.println("GET POPULAR RAN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                getRecommendedData(MenuList.get(0).getRecommended());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server is not responding.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




    }

    private void  getPopularData(List<Popular> popularList){

        popularRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.popular_recycler);
        popularAdapter = new PopularAdapter(this, popularList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        popularRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        popularRecyclerView.setAdapter(popularAdapter);

    }

    private void  getRecommendedData(List<Recommended> recommendedList){

        recommendedRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recommended_recycler);
        recommendedAdapter = new RecommendedAdapter(this, recommendedList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recommendedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recommendedRecyclerView.setAdapter(recommendedAdapter);

    }

    private void  getAllMenu(List<Allmenu> allmenuList){

        allMenuRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.all_menu_recycler);
        allMenuAdapter = new AllMenuAdapter(this, allmenuList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        allMenuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        allMenuRecyclerView.setAdapter(allMenuAdapter);
        allMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

FoodDetails

```
{

    // now we will get data from intent and set to UI

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView itemName, itemPrice, itemRating;
    RatingBar ratingBar;

    String name, price, rating, imageUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        price = intent.getStringExtra("price");
        rating = intent.getStringExtra("rating");
        imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("image");

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        itemName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        itemPrice = findViewById(R.id.price);
        itemRating = findViewById(R.id.rating);
        ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
        itemName.setText(name);
        itemPrice.setText("$ "+price);
        itemRating.setText(rating);
        ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating));

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `call.enqueue` **did** get called and both `onResponse` and `onFailure` **didn't**?

Comment: Use log.d("tag","message") to log your errors and messages rather than system.out.print.

Comment: @HenryTwist I am at least 100% sure `onResponse` did not. After running some tests on the code I believe a `call.enqueue` isn't running.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. You always want to do your tests before posting a question, it will save you so much time in the future if you can find issues yourself. Then if you still need to ask a question you can let us know exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: @henrytwist So would you advise I write a new problem?

Comment: Either that or [edit] this one, as it hasn't had much attention or answers it won't make much difference. Just make sure you've fully narrowed the problem down and find out exactly where the issue starts. Then produce a [mre] that demonstrates your issue in a few lines. Most of your code you have currently posted has nothing to do with your problem at the moment. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of silly mistakes are there. I have fixed all your bugs. Nothing wrong with your `JSON` or `Response` data classes. Correct `response` is received inside `onResponse()` callback. Issues are present other parts of your code. Just follow step by step.

**Step-1**

Replace below code while parsing `response` data from `api` call like:

```
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<FoodData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Response<List<FoodData>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                if (response.body() != null){
                    List<Popular> popular = response.body().get(0).getPopular();

                    getPopularData(popular);

                    getRecommendedData(response.body().get(0).getRecommended());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server is not responding.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**Step-2**

Inside `PopularAdapter` class replace `getItemCount()` method as below:

```
    @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return 0;   // Returning 0 will show nothing in RecyclerView.
   return popularList.size();
}
```

**Step-3:**

Inside `RecommendedAdapter` class you have used wrong `xml` for `ViewHolder`. Replace like below:

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public RecommendedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.popular_recycler_items, parent, false);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recommended_recyvler_items, parent, false);
    return new RecommendedViewHolder(view);
}
```

And also replace `getItemCount()` method like below:

```
    @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recommendedList.size();
}
```

**UPDATE:-**

Why are you calling same `api` inside `onSuccess()` of `api` call ? I have update your `onCreate()` method like below:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<FoodData>> call = apiInterface.getAllData();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<FoodData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Response<List<FoodData>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    getPopularData(response.body().get(0).getPopular());
                    getRecommendedData(response.body().get(0).getRecommended());
                    getAllMenu(response.body().get(0).getAllmenu());
                }
            }
        /*              
     call.clone().enqueue(new Callback<List<FoodData>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Response<List<FoodData>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            response.code();
                            getPopularData(response.body().get(0).getPopular());
                            getRecommendedData(response.body().get(0).getRecommended());
                            getAllMenu(response.body().get(0).getAllmenu());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Throwable t) {
                    response.code();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<FoodData>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I was able to fix all those issues and some other syntax errors. Now I am running into something else I have no idea about. Do you mind helping? The code is up to date on GitHub. 
```
Process: com.example.bearcateats, PID: 9332
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed.
     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:88)
     at 
retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.enqueue(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:62)
     at com.example.bearcateats.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:49) 
```

Comment: I have made changes to my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I see your JSON in https://francescainfranca.github.io/menuJSON/index.json is an Single FoodData JSON Object and Not an JSONArray.

This is causing the following exception when we run the application. So either Change the JSON structure or Make the application use **FoodData** directly instead of **List<FoodData>**.[image]

Also the Toast Message (**Server is not responding**) is being shown on run which you have added on Failure Response.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit iffy on the JSON syntax. I edited the JSON to be an array by adding a square bracket at the beginning and end of the file, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Replace your response body with this code

`List<FoodData> MenuList = response.body();
if (MenuList != null && MenuList.size() > 0) {
    FoodData foodData = MenuList.get(0);
    getPopularData(foodData.getPopular());
    getRecommendedData(foodData.getRecommended());
} else {
    System.out.println("No Items Found!");
}`

And RecommendedAdapter.java replace layout file "popular_recycler_items" with "recommended_recyvler_items"

This should fix your issues.